# iOS test suite - Adding the whole project sources to test

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, unit-testing, cocoapods

As I started to use test suites I realized (supposing I'm not doing anything wrong) that I have to manually add all the sources I want to use in my test suites.

i.e: if in my main project I have `MyClass.swift`, I have to go to the `Test target > Build Phases > Compile Sources` and add all the sources I want to compile.

Also, I can't see my Cocoapods frameworks there without going into `Test target > Build Phases > Link Binary With Libraries` and adding `Pods_MyProject`.

I just want to know if this is how we always have to do.

Answer (score 2):

You do not need to add the sources at all.

At the top of each test file. import your module to test.

So if your apps name is UIKitTesting you would import it like so

```
@testable import UIKitTesting
```

Comment: When I do that I got the message "Missing required module 'Firebase'". That's why I added all the sources. I realized that even with the sources added manually I got the message saying that ObjectMapper module could not be found.

Comment: in your podfile you can include pods in the test target if you are using alamofire specific code in your tests, just add it to the test target

Comment: Well, I deleted all the MyAppTest target and folder, recreated it and inside my Podfile I added a test target inside the main one and added `inherit! :search_paths` on it. That fixed my problem but, sincerely, I don't know why.

Comment: I'm not sure on the search paths bit to be honest. but I'm glad you sorted your issue. It sounds like the search paths will be where it will look for modules/source code. at least now you know about the @testable import :D Good luck with the project

Comment: Even though It's working now, I _must_ import all the modules I'll use even  if they are already imported inside my classes, or else I got a match-o link error. Is this normal?

Comment: no, what modules are you talking about, just pods or literally all? with you changing built settings/rules, deleting the test target and adding again you may have caused some unexpected issues

Comment: I'm talking about Pods I use. Let's say that inside one class of my main project I use Alamofire. If I instantiate this class in the test case without importing Alamofire in my test suite, I got the Match-o link error.

Comment: I believe that when I last setup a project like this I created a shared_pods target in the podfile and then included that in both my app target and test target. so that the pods were available in both. but i dont think that is the best solution.

Comment: Make sure you're on CocoaPods 1.4.0. Otherwise you'll run into https://github.com/firebase/firebase-ios-sdk/issues/58

Comment: I'm using CocoaPods 1.4.0.

Answer (score 0):

For testing you need to include pods that you want to work when your are testing.
Example using Kingfisher for images and you need to test using that framework, you need po add in your pod file.

Below pod file, add pods for testing:

```
platform :ios, '10.2'

// default name so we don't repeat

def pods
  pod 'Kingfisher'
  pod 'Firebase/Messaging'
end


target 'ProjectName' do

  # Comment the next line if you don't want to use dynamic frameworks
  use_frameworks!

  pods

target 'ProjectNameTests' do

    inherit! :search_paths
    # Pods for testing

    pods
  end


end
```